# createAppContainer not working even after exporting

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, expo

Hi I am new to react native , i was trying to set up basic routing in react-native expo, i am unable to figure out what I am missing.
Here is my 
app.js -

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer  } from "react-navigation";
import LoginScreen  from "./src/components/screen/LoginScreen"
import HomeScreen  from "./src/components/screen/HomeScreen"


const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
LoginScreen: {
screen: LoginScreen
},
HomeScreen: {
screen: HomeScreen
}
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
 return (
     <AppNavigator />
 );
  }
 }
```

Here is my HomeScreen.js -

```
import React from "react";
import {
ScrollView,
Text,
View,
} from 'react-native';
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {


render() {
    return (
        <View >
            <ScrollView >
                <Text>Home Screen</Text>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my LoginScreen.js -

```
import React from "react";
import {
ScrollView,
Text,
View,
Button,
} from 'react-native';
import HomeScreen from "./HomeScreen"

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {


render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }} >
                <Text>LoginScreen</Text>
                <Button onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')} title = "Go To Home" />
        </View>
    );
 }
}
```

It would be really helpful if someone could suggest what is it , that i am missing , i am able to see login screen with a button but nothing happens on click (no routing). I tested the click , it is working fine  with android-toast.

Comment: Have you tried with `() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen)`?

Comment: i have , have updated the post as well

Comment: Try logging this.props in the constructor to see if the navigation prop is actually there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must export the AppNavigator directly.

```
const App = createAppNavigator(RootStack);

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks. i exported my app class and rendered my appNavigator from there why did that does not work ?

Comment: If you want to do additional stuff in App.js and would like to keep the App class you need to provide the props as well: render() {return ( <AppNavigator{...this.props} />);}

Answer (score 0):

Add App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter,Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import LoginScreen  from "./src/components/screen/LoginScreen"
import HomeScreen  from "./src/components/screen/HomeScreen"

class RootStack  extends React.Component {
     <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={LoginScreen} />
                    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={HomeScreen} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
)


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <RootStack  />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```